# pgfplots ignores xmin/xmax with 'axis equal' option

Tags: pgfplots

It seems that if I set `axis equal` option with pgfplots, the `xmin` and `xmax` options are not obeyed.  The MWE below yields:

[image]

Note that the `ymin` and `ymax` are as desired in both cases, but the limits on the x-axis are *not* with `axis equal` option:

I would like to have `axis equal` but *also* be able to specify the limits on the `xmim` and `xmax` to which the axis is drawn.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis y line=center,
    axis x line=middle, 
    xmin=-8,
    xmax=8,
    ymin=-8,
    ymax=8,
    xtick={-8, -6, ..., 8},
    ytick={-8, -6, ..., 8},
    ylabel={axis equal},
    axis equal,
    ]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis y line=center,
    axis x line=middle, 
    xmin=-8,
    xmax=8,
    ymin=-8,
    ymax=8,
    xtick={-8, -6, ..., 8},
    ytick={-8, -6, ..., 8},
    ylabel={without axis equal},
    %axis equal, <--- main change from above
    ]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: is it the same if you move the axis equal key earlier (first)?

Comment: @percusse: Good idea, but still same results.

Comment: It does say it will change the limits in the documentation. But I don't know why it needs to in this case.

Comment: Are not they both desired results? `axis equal` sets `unit rescale keep size=true` so that PGFPLOTS will enlarge `xmax`&`xmin` to fit the expected size of the final `tikzpicture`.

Comment: I think you're looking for the `axis equal image` option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are three group of parameters:

- `xmax`-family
- the length of unit vectors.
- the size of the resulting `tikzpicture`

And subsequently three ratios:

- **A** = (`xmax`-`xmin`)/(`ymax`-`ymin`)
- **B** = |x-unit vector|/|y-unit vector|
- **C** = width/height (of `tikzpicture`)

Clearly **A** × **B** = **C**.

To control **B**, PGFPLOTS introduces `unit vector ratio`. Now if **B** is specified, PGFPLOTS has two choices:

- keep `xmax`-family for that, in this case, they are specified by user; or
- keep width and height.

So PGFPLOTS introduces another option called `unit rescale keep size`, where "size" means width and height. If true, **C** is preserved. If false, **A** is preserved.

Go back to your question: `axis equal` is constructed as follows
(`pgfplots.code.tex` line 1772-1779)

> ```
> /pgfplots/axis equal/.is choice,
> /pgfplots/axis equal/true/.style={
>   /pgfplots/unit vector ratio=1 1 1,
>   /pgfplots/unit rescale keep size=true
> },
> /pgfplots/axis equal/false/.style={
>   /pgfplots/unit vector ratio=,
> },
> /pgfplots/axis equal/.default=true,
> ```

So we might say that `axis equal` is an option that specifies **B** and **C**, and then adjust **A** to fit them. It is NOT an option that keeps **A** and **C**.

Comment: Nice explanation! And if you use `axis equal image` instead of `axis equal`, **A** and **B** are fixed and **C** is adjusted to fit them.

Comment: Yes, very good explanation of what is going. But, is the solution then to _not use `axis equal` and instead use `/pgfplots/unit vector ratio=1 1 1`?

Comment: @PeterGrill Honestly I am not sure what you want. What I know is possible now are fixing **AB** and fixing **BC**. I have no clue how to fix **AC** if we do not assign `xmax`-family manually. There might be some magic option regarding `enlargelimits`. I just do not know.

Comment: The solution I went with is to define `\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/my axis equal/.style={/pgfplots/unit vector ratio=1 1 1}}` and use `my axis equal` instead of `axis equal`.