# How to scale TikZ graph 1:1 and shade area between curves

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics, diagrams, polar

I'm trying to replicate this image with TikZ.

[image: area between polar coordinates]

So far, I've been able to do this:

[image]

But the scaling is a little bit weird, I'd like to make it 1:1 since it looks stretched. And also to color that area, I've seen other examples but the problem with this one is that the curves do not generate at the same time.

```
\begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \begin{axis}
        % Outer curve
        \addplot [data cs=polar, domain=0:360, samples=180, white,
            line width=1pt, smooth](x, {3*cos(3*x)});
        % Inner curve
        \addplot [data cs=polar, domain=0:360, samples=180, white,
            line width=1pt, smooth](x, {1+2*sin(x)});
        % Shading        
        
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture} 
        \end{center}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I do not know why someone downvoted this. I searched the site for "aspect ratio" and got some indications that one could get it with `axis equal` or so. I hope that helps.

Comment: I also don't know why this was so quickly downvoted, but you should always provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a [Metapost](https://tug.org/metapost.html) version for comparison:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
numeric u; u = 60;    
path xx, yy, limacon, propeller;
xx = (left -- right) scaled 3.5u;
yy = xx rotated 90;
limacon = (for t = 0 upto 359: (1 + 2 sind(t)) * dir t .. endfor cycle) scaled u;
propeller = (for t = 0 upto 179: (3 cosd(3t)) * dir t .. endfor cycle) scaled u;

path shaded_area; 
shaded_area = buildcycle(
    subpath (90, 120) of propeller,
    subpath (90, 150) of limacon, 
    subpath (120, 150) of propeller, 
    subpath (330, 270) of limacon);

fill shaded_area withcolor 3/4[blue, white];

% This is useful to work out the correct subpaths of the shapes for buildcycle
% for i=0 step 30 until length limacon - 1:   dotlabel.top(decimal i, point i of limacon); endfor
% for i=0 step 20 until length propeller - 1: dotlabel.top(decimal i, point i of propeller); endfor

draw limacon;    
draw propeller;  

drawarrow xx; label.rt("$x$", point 1 of xx);
drawarrow yy; label.top("$y$", point 1 of yy);

for t = -2, 2:
    draw (left--right) shifted (0, t*u); label.lft("$" & decimal t & "$", (0, t*u));
    draw (down--up) shifted (t*u, 0); label.bot("$" & decimal t & "$", (t*u, 0));
endfor

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Compile this with `lualatex` to get:

[image]

If you really wanted a white-on-black version, here is one way to do that in Metapost.

- delete the line `fill shaded_area withcolor 3/4[blue, white]`
- and add these five lines just before the `endfig;`

  ```
    picture P; P = currentpicture; currentpicture := nullpicture;
    bboxmargin := 20;
    fill bbox P withcolor black;
    fill shaded_area withcolor 3/4[blue, white];
    draw P withcolor white;
  ```
- then compile again with `lualatex` to get this version:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As proposed in the comments to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/287022/47927), if you want to set `xmin` and `xmax` as well as `ymin` and `ymax`, using `axis equal image` would be the way to go to obtain an aspect ratio of 1:1. In the below example, I added the shading using the `fillbetween` and the `backgrounds` library.

Due to rounding errors, the intersections of the two paths, especially the one at the origin where the paths meet multiple times, might not be accurately calculated. To solve this problem, I shifted the domains of the paths such that they both start and end at the origin, which is a critical coordinate for drawing the shape.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{fillbetween, backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            axis equal image,
            axis lines=center,
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
            xmin=-3.75, xmax=3.75,
            ymin=-3.75, ymax=3.75
        ]
        % Outer curve
        \addplot[data cs=polar, domain=-30:150, samples=257, red,
            line width=1pt, name path=A] (x, {3*cos(3*x)});
        % Inner curve
        \addplot[data cs=polar, domain=-30:330, samples=257, blue,
            line width=1pt, name path=B] (x, {1+2*sin(x)});
        % Shading
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
            \fill[yellow, intersection segments={of=A and B, 
                sequence={L4 -- R4 -- L6 -- R6[reverse]}}] -- cycle;
        \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Impressive! I didn't even know this `sequence` command that you used. Is there a documentation on that somewhere?

Comment: @SebGlav Yes in the PGFPlots manual in chapter 5.7.6 "Intersection Segment Recombination" (the `fillbetween` library can be loaded with `\usepgfplotslibrary` as well as with `\usetikzlibrary`.